# i want to count total number of males and females from the result of sub query. Is there any mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT name,gender FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.form_id WHERE table1.city ="Banglore";
```

The above query displays name and gender of people located in banglore.

```
   Name      Gender
 ___________________
   Riya      Female 
   Ramesh    Male
   Anand     Male
   preety    Female
   Rakesh    Male
```

Now i want to count the total number of records, total number of males and total number of females from the above query result.
(i.e) Output should be table with data (name, gender, total_count = 5, total_males = 3, total_females = 2).

Is there any such mysql query?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) as total,
       sum(gender = 'Female') as females,
       sum(gender = 'Male') as males
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.form_id 
WHERE table1.city = 'Banglore'
```

If you want to put all that together this would be an ugly query for MySQL with versions below 8.0. But with MySQL 8+ you could simply do

```
select name, gender, 
       count(*) over() as total,
       sum(gender = 'Male') over() as males,
       sum(gender = 'Female') over() as females
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.form_id 
WHERE table1.city = 'Banglore'
```

Comment: Can you please help me to join this output to my previous query result (i.e) output should be table with data/columns... name, gender, total, females , males.

Comment: What Version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: PHP my admin with version below 8.0

Comment: In that case I would run 2 separate queries.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation

```
select count(*), count(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as MaleCount,
count(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as femalecount
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.form_id 
WHERE table1.city ="Banglore"
```

Comment: Can you please help me to join this output to my previous query result (i.e) output should be table with data/columns... name, gender, total, females , males